# Rubik's cube as $2\times2\times2$ or $2\times2$?

Tags: rubiks-cube

I'm surprised why people call a Rubik's cube as $2 \times2\times2$ or $3\times3\times3$? It's a CUBE!
Isn't saying $2\times2$ or $3\times3$ cube (or rather just $2$ or $3$) sufficient?

Comment: It's a CUBE!  Doesn't $2$ or $3$ explain it fully?

Comment: Explain what? $~$

Comment: damn! that's a slap on my face. But still, what's the reason for all this redundancy?

Comment: In fact, *the* Rubik's cube already is a sufficient nameing for the toy made out of $21$ parts with $54$ coloured fields, of which $48$ can change their position relative to the fixed frame.

Comment: and what's the problem? :|

Comment: There are [3x4x5](http://amzn.to/XWlihb) puzzles as well. All sides having an equal length isn't a given.

Answer (score 4):

Cube is a 3D object. It has got three dimensions. So basically, $3 \times 3 \times 3$ means 3 columns, each column with 3 boxes and 3 rows of such columns  .

Or in terms of mensuration, you can think of it as a cube 3 units long, 3 units wide and 3 units high.

Comment: Really? 3 faces? Are you _sure_ about that?